# How to invoke EventHandler from a different class in JavaFX

Tags: java, events, javafx, event-handling

Say I have the following code that is built to trigger an event when someone pushes a button B0:

```
        B0.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

         //DoSomething

        }

    });
```

This works fine and is easier in most cases but when I need to do this for 20+ buttons it becomes difficult to create an individual method for each Button so a much more preferred way of working things would be a large amount of if statement's to dictate the source of the event in a different class (organization purposes).

What I need to know is how to invoke the EventHandler from this in a separate class (such as the code below) and get a valid return so the program can continue.

```
public class Logic{

   public final EventHandler<ActionEvent> getOnAction() {
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: `EventHandler` is an interface, why not implement it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried that before and hit a road block with calling it in the first Code example I gave. Can you explain how you'd go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`EventHandler<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) is an `interface`, why not just `implement` it?

```
public class SupaDupaHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    }

}
```

Then in your code you could just do...

```
SupaDupaHandler handler = new SupaDupaHandler();
btn.setOnAction(handler);
// And repeat 20 times
```

Or directly...

```
btn.setOnAction(new SupaDupaHandler());
```

depending on your needs

Comment: Man, I have no idea why I didn't just do that in the first place. Thanks for the help again! I do believe you've helped me in the past actually.

Comment: Welcome to the forest, look out for the trees ;)